# Задержка для выпадающего меню

Tags: html, css

Видел похожие вопросы и пробовал то, что предлагается там, но у меня не срабатывает никак.

Такое меню:

```
<nav class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">Home</a>
            <div class="dropdown-nav">
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <h1>Special offer!</h1>
                    <p>Some picture here</p>
                </div>



            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">Men</a>
            <div class="dropdown-nav">
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Clothing</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Shirts</a>
                    <a href="#">Jackets</a>
                    <a href="#">Trousers</a>
                    <a href="#">Underwear</a>
                    <a href="#">Sports</a>


                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Shoes</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Boots</a>
                    <a href="#">Sneakers</a>
                    <a href="#">Sandals</a>
                    <a href="#">Loafers</a>
                    <a href="#">Brogues</a>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Accessories</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Glasses</a>
                    <a href="#">Gloves</a>
                    <a href="#">Hats</a>
                    <a href="#">Bags</a>
                    <a href="#">Belts</a>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Jewelry</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Bracelets</a>
                    <a href="#">Earrings</a>
                    <a href="#">Necklaces</a>
                    <a href="#">Rings</a>
                    <a href="#">Cufflinks</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">Women</a>
            <div class="dropdown-nav">
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Clothing</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Shirts</a>
                    <a href="#">Jackets</a>
                    <a href="#">Trousers</a>
                    <a href="#">Underwear</a>
                    <a href="#">Sports</a>


                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Shoes</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Boots</a>
                    <a href="#">Sneakers</a>
                    <a href="#">Sandals</a>
                    <a href="#">Loafers</a>
                    <a href="#">Brogues</a>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Accessories</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Glasses</a>
                    <a href="#">Gloves</a>
                    <a href="#">Hats</a>
                    <a href="#">Bags</a>
                    <a href="#">Belts</a>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Jewelry</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Bracelets</a>
                    <a href="#">Earrings</a>
                    <a href="#">Necklaces</a>
                    <a href="#">Rings</a>
                    <a href="#">Cufflinks</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">Kids</a>
            <div class="dropdown-nav">
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Clothing</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Shirts</a>
                    <a href="#">Jackets</a>
                    <a href="#">Trousers</a>
                    <a href="#">Underwear</a>
                    <a href="#">Sports</a>


                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Shoes</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Boots</a>
                    <a href="#">Sneakers</a>
                    <a href="#">Sandals</a>
                    <a href="#">Loafers</a>
                    <a href="#">Brogues</a>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Accessories</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Glasses</a>
                    <a href="#">Gloves</a>
                    <a href="#">Hats</a>
                    <a href="#">Bags</a>
                    <a href="#">Belts</a>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Jewelry</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Bracelets</a>
                    <a href="#">Earrings</a>
                    <a href="#">Necklaces</a>
                    <a href="#">Rings</a>
                    <a href="#">Cufflinks</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">Accessories</a>
            <div class="dropdown-nav">
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>All accessories</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Shirts</a>
                    <a href="#">Jackets</a>
                    <a href="#">Trousers</a>
                    <a href="#">Underwear</a>
                    <a href="#">Sports</a>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Wallets</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Boots</a>
                    <a href="#">Sneakers</a>
                    <a href="#">Sandals</a>
                    <a href="#">Loafers</a>
                    <a href="#">Brogues</a>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Sunglasses</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Glasses</a>
                    <a href="#">Gloves</a>
                    <a href="#">Hats</a>
                    <a href="#">Bags</a>
                    <a href="#">Belts</a>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Sale accessories</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Bracelets</a>
                    <a href="#">Earrings</a>
                    <a href="#">Necklaces</a>
                    <a href="#">Rings</a>
                    <a href="#">Cufflinks</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">Featured</a>
            <div class="dropdown-nav">
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Homeware</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Shirts</a>
                    <a href="#">Jackets</a>
                    <a href="#">Trousers</a>
                    <a href="#">Underwear</a>
                    <a href="#">Sports</a>


                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Decorative</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Boots</a>
                    <a href="#">Sneakers</a>
                    <a href="#">Sandals</a>
                    <a href="#">Loafers</a>
                    <a href="#">Brogues</a>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>All jewelery</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Glasses</a>
                    <a href="#">Gloves</a>
                    <a href="#">Hats</a>
                    <a href="#">Bags</a>
                    <a href="#">Belts</a>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Fine jewlery</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Bracelets</a>
                    <a href="#">Earrings</a>
                    <a href="#">Necklaces</a>
                    <a href="#">Rings</a>
                    <a href="#">Cufflinks</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">Hot Deals </a>
            <div class="dropdown-nav">
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Clothing</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Shirts</a>
                    <a href="#">Jackets</a>
                    <a href="#">Trousers</a>
                    <a href="#">Underwear</a>
                    <a href="#">Sports</a>


                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Shoes</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Boots</a>
                    <a href="#">Sneakers</a>
                    <a href="#">Sandals</a>
                    <a href="#">Loafers</a>
                    <a href="#">Brogues</a>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Accessories</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Glasses</a>
                    <a href="#">Gloves</a>
                    <a href="#">Hats</a>
                    <a href="#">Bags</a>
                    <a href="#">Belts</a>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Jewelry</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Bracelets</a>
                    <a href="#">Earrings</a>
                    <a href="#">Necklaces</a>
                    <a href="#">Rings</a>
                    <a href="#">Cufflinks</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

</nav>
```

CSS

```
.menu{
    height: 51px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 780px;
    margin: 0 auto;


}
nav ul {
    width: 680px;
    height: 51px;
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
nav li {
    height: 51px;
    line-height: 51px;
}
nav a {
    opacity: 1;
    color: #222222;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 26px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 17px 7px;
    position: relative;
}
nav a:visited {
    color: #222222;
}
nav li:hover{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ef5b70;
}
nav li:hover .dropdown-nav{
    display: flex;
}
.dropdown-nav{
    display: none;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    height: 365px;
}

.dropdown-nav-item{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    margin-right: 100px;
}
.dropdown-nav-item a{
    width: 100%;

}
.dropdown-nav-item h1{
    margin-top: 30px;
    color: #ef5b70;
    font-size: 75px;
}
.dropdown-nav-item h1:hover{
    background-color: transparent;!important;
}
.dropdown-nav-item a:hover{
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

Для удобства
https://codepen.io/serg-yefr/pen/GRpPYrv

Заранее благодарен

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `display: none` и `display: flex` можно использовать `visibility: hidden` и `visibility: visible`, для задержки ставим `transition` и `transition-delay`, ну и для плавного появления можно использовать переход прозрачности `opacity`

```css
.menu{
    height: 51px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 780px;
    margin: 0 auto;


}
nav ul {
    width: 680px;
    height: 51px;
    display: flex;
    list-style-type: none;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
nav li {
    height: 51px;
    line-height: 51px;
}
nav a {
    opacity: 1;
    color: #222222;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 26px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 17px 7px;
    position: relative;
}
nav a:visited {
    color: #222222;
}
nav li:hover{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ef5b70;
}
nav li:hover .dropdown-nav{
    transition: .4s ease-out;
    transition-delay: .3s;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
.dropdown-nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

.dropdown-nav-item{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    margin-right: 100px;
}
.dropdown-nav-item a{
    width: 100%;

}
.dropdown-nav-item h1{
    margin-top: 30px;
    color: #ef5b70;
    font-size: 75px;
}
.dropdown-nav-item h1:hover{
    background-color: transparent;!important;
}
.dropdown-nav-item a:hover{
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">Home</a>
            <div class="dropdown-nav">
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <h1>Special offer!</h1>
                    <p>Some picture here</p>
                </div>



            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">Men</a>
            <div class="dropdown-nav">
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Clothing</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Shirts</a>
                    <a href="#">Jackets</a>
                    <a href="#">Trousers</a>
                    <a href="#">Underwear</a>
                    <a href="#">Sports</a>


                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Shoes</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Boots</a>
                    <a href="#">Sneakers</a>
                    <a href="#">Sandals</a>
                    <a href="#">Loafers</a>
                    <a href="#">Brogues</a>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Accessories</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Glasses</a>
                    <a href="#">Gloves</a>
                    <a href="#">Hats</a>
                    <a href="#">Bags</a>
                    <a href="#">Belts</a>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Jewelry</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Bracelets</a>
                    <a href="#">Earrings</a>
                    <a href="#">Necklaces</a>
                    <a href="#">Rings</a>
                    <a href="#">Cufflinks</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">Women</a>
            <div class="dropdown-nav">
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Clothing</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Shirts</a>
                    <a href="#">Jackets</a>
                    <a href="#">Trousers</a>
                    <a href="#">Underwear</a>
                    <a href="#">Sports</a>


                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Shoes</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Boots</a>
                    <a href="#">Sneakers</a>
                    <a href="#">Sandals</a>
                    <a href="#">Loafers</a>
                    <a href="#">Brogues</a>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Accessories</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Glasses</a>
                    <a href="#">Gloves</a>
                    <a href="#">Hats</a>
                    <a href="#">Bags</a>
                    <a href="#">Belts</a>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Jewelry</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Bracelets</a>
                    <a href="#">Earrings</a>
                    <a href="#">Necklaces</a>
                    <a href="#">Rings</a>
                    <a href="#">Cufflinks</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">Kids</a>
            <div class="dropdown-nav">
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Clothing</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Shirts</a>
                    <a href="#">Jackets</a>
                    <a href="#">Trousers</a>
                    <a href="#">Underwear</a>
                    <a href="#">Sports</a>


                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Shoes</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Boots</a>
                    <a href="#">Sneakers</a>
                    <a href="#">Sandals</a>
                    <a href="#">Loafers</a>
                    <a href="#">Brogues</a>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Accessories</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Glasses</a>
                    <a href="#">Gloves</a>
                    <a href="#">Hats</a>
                    <a href="#">Bags</a>
                    <a href="#">Belts</a>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Jewelry</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Bracelets</a>
                    <a href="#">Earrings</a>
                    <a href="#">Necklaces</a>
                    <a href="#">Rings</a>
                    <a href="#">Cufflinks</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">Accessories</a>
            <div class="dropdown-nav">
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>All accessories</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Shirts</a>
                    <a href="#">Jackets</a>
                    <a href="#">Trousers</a>
                    <a href="#">Underwear</a>
                    <a href="#">Sports</a>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Wallets</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Boots</a>
                    <a href="#">Sneakers</a>
                    <a href="#">Sandals</a>
                    <a href="#">Loafers</a>
                    <a href="#">Brogues</a>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Sunglasses</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Glasses</a>
                    <a href="#">Gloves</a>
                    <a href="#">Hats</a>
                    <a href="#">Bags</a>
                    <a href="#">Belts</a>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Sale accessories</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Bracelets</a>
                    <a href="#">Earrings</a>
                    <a href="#">Necklaces</a>
                    <a href="#">Rings</a>
                    <a href="#">Cufflinks</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">Featured</a>
            <div class="dropdown-nav">
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Homeware</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Shirts</a>
                    <a href="#">Jackets</a>
                    <a href="#">Trousers</a>
                    <a href="#">Underwear</a>
                    <a href="#">Sports</a>


                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Decorative</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Boots</a>
                    <a href="#">Sneakers</a>
                    <a href="#">Sandals</a>
                    <a href="#">Loafers</a>
                    <a href="#">Brogues</a>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>All jewelery</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Glasses</a>
                    <a href="#">Gloves</a>
                    <a href="#">Hats</a>
                    <a href="#">Bags</a>
                    <a href="#">Belts</a>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Fine jewlery</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Bracelets</a>
                    <a href="#">Earrings</a>
                    <a href="#">Necklaces</a>
                    <a href="#">Rings</a>
                    <a href="#">Cufflinks</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a class="menu-item" href="#">Hot Deals </a>
            <div class="dropdown-nav">
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Clothing</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Shirts</a>
                    <a href="#">Jackets</a>
                    <a href="#">Trousers</a>
                    <a href="#">Underwear</a>
                    <a href="#">Sports</a>


                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Shoes</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Boots</a>
                    <a href="#">Sneakers</a>
                    <a href="#">Sandals</a>
                    <a href="#">Loafers</a>
                    <a href="#">Brogues</a>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Accessories</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Glasses</a>
                    <a href="#">Gloves</a>
                    <a href="#">Hats</a>
                    <a href="#">Bags</a>
                    <a href="#">Belts</a>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-nav-item">
                    <a href="#"><b>Jewelry</b></a>
                    <a href="#">Bracelets</a>
                    <a href="#">Earrings</a>
                    <a href="#">Necklaces</a>
                    <a href="#">Rings</a>
                    <a href="#">Cufflinks</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

</nav>
```